# reduce() can't be interpreted?

Tags: python

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:42:36) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def add(x,y): return x+y
... reduce(add, range(1, 11))
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    reduce(add, range(1, 11))
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am new to python.

Any idea?

I am guessing `reduce()` isn't available in 2.6.6; is there a way to check?  I only see 2.6.9 online document, which has `reduce()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using invalid Python syntax; it is not the `reduce()` call that is the problem.

In the interactive interpreter, you *must* close a compound block statement with a newline:

```
>>> def add(x,y): return x+y
... 
>>> reduce(add, range(1, 11))
55
```

Note the empty `...` after the `def add()` definition.

Quoting the [*Interactive input* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/toplevel_components.html#interactive-input) of the top-level components reference documentation:

> Note that a (top-level) compound statement must be followed by a blank line in interactive mode; this is needed to help the parser detect the end of the input.